# HTACCESS, render 404 instead of 403 upon wrong ip

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

Directory viewing would render 403 upon wrong ip:

```
order deny,allow  
deny from all  
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Simple and clear, so lets move on...
then tried to gobble up some code to render 404 instead of 403:

```
order deny,allow  
deny from all  
allow from 111.222.333.444
RedirectMatch 404 ".*\/\..*"
```

And the above does not work, what have I missed?

**SPECS**
1. .htaccess is inside a subdir
2. file is executed by virtualhost

**NB**
And by rendering, I mean recieving headers vs visual trickery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod_rewrite can solve your problem.

Add the following to your htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.5$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Replace **1.2.3.5** with your ip address.

Comment: Ty for responding, is it possible also without Mod_rewrite?

Comment: I dont think if it is possible, because Order directive returns 403.